# Prepare statements in various lines of PHP code without ON CASCADE

Tags: php, mysql

Is there any way to write these sql statements in less lines?

```
$sentence_1 = $conn->prepare("DELETE FROM us_sub WHERE user_id_fk=?");
$sentence_1->bind_param("i", $id);
$sentence_1->execute();

$sentence_2 = $conn->prepare("DELETE FROM users WHERE id=?");
$sentence_2->bind_param("i", $id);
$sentence_2->execute();
```

What it does is to remove a user from the table '`users`' but since it has foreign key, it must be deleted before from the '`us_sub`' table.

I just want to know if it's possible to do it on less lines without using ON DELETE CASCADE, but if it's correct like this I can leave it.

Comment: take a look at delete cascade constrains

Comment: You need even more lines, because such operations should be done in a transaction.

Comment: If you were using PDO, you could eliminate bind_param and just send in the values in the execute statement.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the MySQL referential action [`ON DELETE CASCADE`](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-on-delete-cascade/) to delete the foreign records when the one in your `users` table gets deleted

In your `us_sub` table, specify the foreign key like so:

```sql
CREATE TABLE us_sub (
    --All the fields
    FOREIGN KEY (us_id_fk) REFERENCES users (id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Comment: I would like to do it in a way without using ON DELETE CASCADE. Is it possible? But if my sql statement is correct I could leave it like that. I just wanted to know if it's possible to do it on less lines without using CASCADE.

Comment: A prepared statement can only do one query at a time, so no. Of course you could use `mysqli_multi_query`, but that could lead to security risks, if you're using user input ofcourse. Any particular reason not to use `ON DELETE CASCADE`?

Comment: I wouldn't like to use ON DELETE CASCADE because for that I should delete my table from the database and create it again. I prefer not to delete it because I have data in the table. However, my sql statements work correctly. Is there any security risk in my code?